# Python: Find a string between two special characters, repeatedly

Tags: python, regex

I have a paragraph like this:

```
paragraph = "Dear {{userName}},

You have been registered successfully. Our Manager {{managerName}} will contact soon.

Thanks"
```

I need to parse all the strings within {{}}. There could be many more like that in the paragraph.

I tried this solution:

```
result = re.search('{{(.*)}}',paragraph)
print(result.group(1))
# output is 'userName}} {{ManagerName'
```

Output I wanted is:

```
["userName","managerName",....]
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

paragraph = """Dear {{userName}},
You have been registered successfully. Our Manager {{managerName}} will contact soon.
Thanks"""

print( re.findall(r"\{\{(.*?)\}\}", paragraph) )
```

**Output:**

```
['userName', 'managerName']
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh for saving my time. Worked brilliantly for me.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative solution without needing regex. You can just find the positions of `{{` and `}}` using [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

```
closebrace = 0
while True:
    openbrace = paragraph.find('{{', closebrace)
    if openbrace == -1:
        break
    closebrace = paragraph.find('}}', openbrace)

    # You now have the positions of open and close braces,
    # check if close brace is -1, then do whatever you want with them
    print(openbrace, closebrace)
```

Comment: ...and downvote because saying regex is not necessary on a regex question is such a great sin.

Comment: Gone are the days when people would say "now you have two problems."